# Retrieve properties and methods of a specified object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose such a snippet of html

```
<a name="edit" href="javascript:" onclick="edit_column(this, {{ column.id }})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

the js:

```
function edit_column(the, column_id){
  alert(the)}
```

On clicking, it alerts "javascript:"

I tried to retrieve more info about it with

```
function edit_column(the, column_id){
  alert(typeof the)}
```

It alert `object`

How could I retrieve properties and method of such a specified object, like `dir` or `vars` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the object's enumerable own property names (and then use those to look up the values) or, in modern environments, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which gives you the names and values (as an array of arrays where each of the subordinate arrays is in the form `[name, value]`). If you need information about non-enumerable properties, there are also [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) and (if you need to look at its prototype) [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

But your specific example is a DOM element (an `HTMLAnchorElement` instance, to be precise), so you can also look up its properties and methods in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element).

> On clicking, it alerts "javascript:"

If you're wondering why that is, it's because `alert` coerces its argument to string, and the string an `HTMLAnchorElement` produces when you do that is its `href` property's value.

Comment: Thanks for your tutorial, I tried `alert(Object.keys(the))` , `alert(Object.entries(the))`  and `alert(Object.entries($(the)))`, it prompt blank with no information.

Comment: @JawSaw - That doesn't surprise me, I think most DOM elements have only inherited properties, not own properties.

Comment: got it. I am doing searches to understand your comments.